# Hidden tax summary from sales mail and order summary/review

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, tax, pdf

we running `Magento 1.8.1.0` , we need to `hidden` the following lines (marked in red in the picture) from order summary and `sales mail/pdf` : Tax and Grand Total to be Charged.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to comment the following line from:

> app/design/frontend/[interface]/[theme]/template/tax/order/tax.phtml:

```
<td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
    <?php if ($this->displayFullSummary()): ?>
        <div class="summary-collapse"><?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</td>
<td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_source->getTaxAmount()) ?></td>
```

Comment: worked! thanks. also to remove the "Grand Total to be Charged" you must: Edit this file /app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/sales/order/totals.phtml and after line #29 insert this code: 

$this->removeTotal('base_grandtotal');